# How to outline traced object in AI?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have traced object which contains lots of polygons. Something like this:

[image]

What I want is to outline this object similar to stroke, with solid color. How to 
create a simple object which is actually outline of my object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group the objects, if they aren't already a group.

Then simply add a new stroke in the **Appearance Panel** and then move the stroke below the *Contents* item.

[image: stroke]

Then, if you want a separate object for the stoke, choose `Object > Expand Appearance`